# need explanation for android layout syntax

Tags: android, layout

here is a line in layout file

```
 <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/username"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
```

**in about context what is the exact meaning of**

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
```

is that related to **"?[package:][type:]name"**  , if yes then what that refers to ?

Comment: what us '?' used for ?  
can we also define same thing ? 
how we can define a new package ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium is referring to the android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium This is the way to reference to external package resource content.

Here's an [article](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/resources/android_resources-i18n_ReferencesToThemeAttributes.html) mentioned this.