# What is the difference between ?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium and ?android:textAppearanceMedium?

Tags: android

I find there are two case in some demo codes, What is the difference between ?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium and ?android:textAppearanceMedium ? Thanks!

Case 1

```
<resources>
    <style name="myTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>
```

Case 2

```
<resources>
    <style name="myTextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceMedium</item>
    </style>  
</resources>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Android Developer API Guide - Accessing Resources - Referencing style attributes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes), the resource type is optional if the system resource tool can figure out the correct resource type. So they are referring to the same value.

Answer (score 5):

I think they both do the same, that is **refer to a theme attribute**.

The DOCS say...

`Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name".`

The `[type:]` being optional.

More explanation in the following links...

[**need explanation for android layout syntax**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669398/need-explanation-for-android-layout-syntax)

[**References to Theme Attributes**](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/resources/android_resources-i18n_ReferencesToThemeAttributes.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are no one difference between 
`?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` and `?android:textAppearanceMedium`.

You can use each of them, as you wish.